# How to know which files have already been copied from source folder to destination folder?

Tags: c#, .net, file, batch-file

I have two folders and I have written a c# code to copy the files from source folder to destination folder. I want to copy these files one by one and also want to change the name of the copied file in destination folder. The problem is, how to know which files have already been copied?

I don't want to use hashcode, as it will be very time consuming if I have more than a million files in the source folder. This will unnecessary check hashcode with all the files present in destination folder. This will affect performance.
Also there is one more constraint, I cannot change any metadata of the files present in source folder.
Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: well, if you can't use the obvious solution of checking the filename, and you can't double check with filesize, you're not going to be left with very many options.

Comment: How are the copied filenames related to the original filenames?

Comment: you mean copied by another program/ or by the user in explorer? or only by this instance of the "copy" program?

Comment: The question is if there is a dependency between the old an the new filenames. If not, I would try to `readline` the first n-lines from a file and compare them against the others. But with more and more files this would take a while. Dont know how big your folder means to get.

Comment: When you copy any file then rename it for ex before copy file1.txt after copy _file1.txt. Just read without underscore at the start of filename

Comment: What do you mean you're doing "one file at a time" ? Can you not just iterate over the collection provided by `Directory.GetFiles`?  You would not necessarily need to "keep track" of the files that were copied, as enumerating over the result could do so for you

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried that if your copying job interrupts then you won't know which files have been copied yet?  Probably a simple way would be to track that information in a table, which can be of various forms, from simple files, XML files, JSON files to a table in a database, and so on.  It can be as basic as:

```
D:\files\file1.dat E:\files\newName1.dat 1
D:\files\file2.dat E:\files\newName2.dat 0
D:\files\file3.dat E:\files\newName3.dat 0
D:\files\file4.dat E:\files\newName4.dat 1
```

First entry is the original file, second entry is destination file (you've mentioned the change of name) and the third entry is whether the file was successfully copied.  I would pre-fill this table, so that if your job restarts, all it has to do is read from this file, instead of getting all the file names from a directory.

Once you resume your copying job, you can simply load up the file and copy the ones that have 0 for the last entry.

If you save it in a basic text file, loading it up can be as basic as:

```
var files = File.ReadLines(filePath)
                .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                .Where(entry => entry[2].Equals("0"));
```

Comment: Thanks Bk. I know database would be the best option. But what if I cant use database as well? I am supposed to check through file explorer only.

Comment: @user3195546 There's always a file database, such as SQLite. Doesn't require any installations; it's just a file. If you can't go that route either, then I'd use a text file. The format that you'll record that data with will depend on your preference... could be JSON, XML, plain text as I've shown above, or any other format you prefer.  The code I showed above just deals with a plain text file.  It should work well. That's of course all assuming that you can't do in-memory one-session deal. If you can, then you don't need any of this.  Just loop through your files and copy them with new names.